# How to identify an object is transient or detached in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I know that transient instance means the instance is newly created and its corresponding row does not exist in the database where as detached instance has corresponding entry in the database but not associated with any session at present.

Is there any way to identify an object is transient or detached using any methods on Session or something else in hibernate programatically?

Answer (score 16):

It sounds like you're looking for [`EntityManager#contains(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29).

> Check if the instance is a managed entity instance belonging to the current persistence context.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt. But I think it checks whether  this instance is associated with persistent context or not right ? I guess it is similar to session.contains(object) in hibernate.

Answer (score 7):

In order to check if object e is in :-

1. Persistence Context :- EntityManager.contains(e) should return true.
2. Detached State : PersistenceUnitUtil.getIdentifier(e) returns the value of the entity’s identifier property.
3. Transient State :- PersistenceUnitUtil.getIdentifier(e) returns null

You can get to the PersistenceUnitUtil from the EntityManagerFactory.

There are two issues to look out for. First, be aware that the identifier value may not
be assigned and available until the persistence context is flushed. Second, Hibernate
(unlike some other JPA providers) never returns null from Persistence-
UnitUtil#getIdentifier() if your identifier property is a primitive (a long and not
a Long).

Comment: Should'nt EntityManager.contains(e) return false for a detached entity?

Answer (score 5):

What Matt suggested would only check if the given object is transient or associated with some entity manager.

If you want to check if it's detached or transient (which you shouldn't really care about! it should be transparent) you need to check if the given object has an ID.

```
if(data.getID() == null) return TRANSIENT;
```

The ID should only be set for persistent/detached objects. If for some reason you are setting the ID yourself on transient objects then I don't think what you want to do is possible.

If you don't know which field is the ID (for some reason) or you want to make it generic you can try:

```
ClassMetadata metadata = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(data.getClass());
if(metadata.getIdentifier(data) == null) return TRANSIENT;
```

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk I didn't downvote, but if you create a object and set it's ID manually, it's still transient, and I think that's the case of most people getting here (like me, I'm getting my object from JSON decode)

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk Also, `getClassMetadata` is reflection, which has it's own performance penalties, IMHO you should let it clear in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try pass a transient object and a detached object to hibernate session update method and watch the difference.For transient object, hibernate will report an error.

So hibernate knows the object is transient or detached. But how? The answer is simple: hibernate will do an select before the update to get the information of which fields are dirty. If the object is transient, the will be no result of that selection operation then hibernate knows this is transient object and report an error.

Or, if you use `@SelectBeforeUpdate(false)`, hibernate will not do the select, instead with an update directly, in this case, jdbc will report error due to the row need to update is not exist.

Of course you can check the id field if it generated by database or else the only way to know its state is do an query: not found means transient.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, `org.hibernate.Session.contains(Object)` may be used in Hibernate to know if an entity instance is attached or detached. Regarding the transient state, the best that could be done I think is what `org.hibernate.Session.saveOrUpdate(Object)` (by virtue of `org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(Object, SessionImplementor)`) does, that is:

- if the entity has no `@Id` property, it's *always* considered transient
- if the entity has an `@Id` property value which is `null`, it's *always* considered transient
- if the entity has an `@Id` property value which is equal to the configured `unsaved-value`, then it's considered transient (only applies to XML mapping, I think it's somewhat deprecated, see [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-id))
- if it has a `@Version` property whose value is the one of a newly created instance (that is, it's a `null` `Long`, or `Date`, etc.), then it's considered transient

Hence, I think that, for entities without a generated id, looking at the `@Version` property is the way to go. If there's no such property, Hibernate itself in `saveOrUpdate` makes a SELECT query against the database to determine whether the entity instance is transient or not, to determine if it should do an INSERT or an UPDATE respectively.

See Hibernate manual (as an example, [4.3 one here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-saveorupdate)).