# JPA and Hibernate: NonUniqueObjectException. Do not understand the cause

Tags: java, hibernate

I run into a problem that is discussed multiple times across SO. Still in this case I do not understand the reason behind:

**org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [model.Asset#AMZN]**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Asset extends Base {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "symbol")
    private String symbol;
    ...

    @Deprecated
    Asset(){}

    public Asset(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }
    
    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Asset asset = (Asset) o;

        return symbol.equals(asset.symbol);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return symbol.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Even so there would be another object, it still would have the same ID wouldn't it? My equals method compares the symbol of my asset. If the symbols of two objects are the same, so are the objects itself? So I wonder why this exception exists in the first place.

Further information. I use the asset for example here like this:

```
public class Trade{
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "symbol")
    private Asset asset;

    ...
}
```

Also I have a class Depot which can contain multiple trades and each trade is associated with an Asset like above:

```
public class Depot{
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "depot_id")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private final Set<Trade> trades= new HashSet<>();
}
```

I load my data from the Database like so:

```
public synchronized <T> List<T> loadAllData(Class<T> type) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> criteria = builder.createQuery(type);
        criteria.from(type);
        List<T> data = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return data;
    }
```

Now, one think you might say is that I should not use `CascadeType.All` as I would delete assets that might be attached to other trades. But I never delete anything in the database. I will only save or update like this:

```
public synchronized void persist(Object item){
        if(!PERSIST_ENABLE) return;
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        try{
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.saveOrUpdate(item);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch (Exception e){
            //This triggers all the time
            logger.error("Error persisting data. Rolling back transaction\n",e);
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Asset is one of two classes where the **NonUniqueObjectException**. I need to understand why.

EDIT:

Complete Stacktrace

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.hoehlsoft.model.Asset#AMZN]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:609)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cascadeOnUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:609)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cascadeOnUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:609)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:532)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:426)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cascadeOnUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:609)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:532)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:426)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cascadeOnUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:609)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cascadeOnUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:609)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:604)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:351)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.saveOrUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at database.Db.persist(Db.java:46)
    at Trader.process(Trader.java:235)
    at Trader.onNewQuoteReceived(Trader.java:100)
    at Main.lambda$new$0(Main.java:30)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

And also the class (well parts of it)

```
public class Trader{
    @JoinColumn(name = "symbol")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected Asset mAsset;

    @JoinColumn(name = "depot_id")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected Depot mDepot;
    ...

    protected synchronized void process(Quote quote) {
    //Does loads of stuff but never touches the mAsset (that is final, so it always is the object loaded from db)
    //This is where it crashes
    if (oldState != mState) Db.access().persist(this);
    }
```

Comment: Show  the stack trace of org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException and the code around.

Comment: Updated with StackTrace

Comment: `//Does loads of stuff but never touches the mAsset (that is final, so it always is the object loaded from db)` that says you, but Hibernate tell you, it is not.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474399/how-to-identify-an-object-is-transient-or-detached-in-hibernate

Comment: No, that literally cannot be the case. I can add the `final` keyword to `mAsset` and no compiler errors occur (besides the one for the needed empty constructor). So i do not create a new object. Also how can two Assets with the same symbold be different objects if equals return true if symbols are the same?

Comment: BTW `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` this is a Code Smell. Why do you need EAGER ?

Comment: Because I will need the data marked with `FetchType.EAGER` anyway at some point in the near future, so why not load them all into memory directly? If you look at Depot class, there I have `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` because I don't need all past trades. But of course I need the Asset, so EAGER seemed okay?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two assets (one is mAsset, other is among mDepot.trades... asset) that are equal (i.e. asset1.equals(asset2)) but they are different objects (i.e. asset1 != asset2). Persisting a trader turns on cascade persisting of included objects but indeed Hibernate concerns having two different objects with the same ID

Comment: Indeed both are referencing an Asset, but it is the same. When I load the Data from the Database I only load the Trader (which cascade loads everything which is needed/EAGER) ... but if it loads the second Asset should Hibernate not be smart enough to see that those are the same (same PK?). What is the workaround? And does Hibernate really uses object identity instead of equals?

Comment: Loading and saving are two different stories. At loading the assets are referencing the very same object. But no, Hibernate is not smart enough to check equality at saving time for nested cascades for the different objects.